# Prevent change of account owner unless its in your name

Tags: validation-rule, validation, owner

Current validation rule which stops account ownership being changed unless you have a system admin profile. I wish to allow account ownership to change if the account is in the users name...any suggestions would be much appreciated...

AND(
not(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( OwnerId ))),
ISCHANGED(OwnerId ),
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator")

Comment: try with below validation rule.

    AND( not(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( OwnerId ))), ISCHANGED(OwnerId ), OR($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",  $User.Id <> OwnerId))

Comment: thank you Ankaiah this works :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am posting this answer.

Comment: Are you trying to allow people to take ownership or give it away?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below validation rule.

```
AND( not(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( OwnerId ))), ISCHANGED(OwnerId ), OR($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", $User.Id <> OwnerId))
```